# MySQL SELECT value from a table column based on a different table and sum()

Tags: mysql

I've got 2 tables setup like so:

```
> events
-----------------------------------
id | event | eventHandle | points
-----------------------------------
1 | Event One | eventOne | 5
2 | Event Two | eventTwo | 10


> entries
-----------------------------------
id | user | eventHandle
-----------------------------------
1 | 1 | eventOne
2 | 1 | eventTwo
3 | 1 | eventTwo
5 | 5 | eventOne
```

And what I need to do is get the amount of 'points' each user has gained related to each event.

For example, user 1 has got 25 points and user 5 has 5 points.

What I can't figure out is how get the points, based one the eventHandle and sum them together.

I managed to select the different data from different tables, and do a basic sum with a different query, but not combined. Mind boggling.

Any help is mighty appreciated!

Comment: You need a [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Comment: join, group by and sum should do it.
`select en.user, sum(points) from events ev inner join entries en on ev.eventHandle = en.eventHandle group by en.user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is a simple `inner join` between the 2 tables on eventHandle fields and sum points by users:

```
select en.user, sum(ev.points)
from events ev
inner join entries en on ev.eventHandle=en.eventHandle
group by en.user
```

Comment: Amazing. That worked perfect and didn't seem as complicated as I thought it would be. I was obviously over engineering it!